# SSH get terminated when starting Ovpn Client

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ssh, routing, vps

I have a VPS running Ubuntu 16.04.1 that I connect to with SSH. I would like to run an OpenVPN client on the VPS so that internet traffic is routed through the VPN, but still allow me to connect to the server via SSH. When I start up OpenVPN, my SSH session gets disconnected and I can no longer connect to my VPS. How can I configure the VPS to allow incoming SSH (port 22) connections to be open on the VPS's actual IP (84.X.x.X), but still route outgoing traffic (like from a web browser on the VPS) through the VPN?

The OpenVPN service I use is PrivateInternetAccess, and an example config.ovpn file is:

```
proto udp
tun-mtu 1500
fragment 1300
mssfix
cipher AES-256-CBC
remote amsterdam.perfect-privacy.com 149
remote amsterdam.perfect-privacy.com 1151
remote amsterdam.perfect-privacy.com 1150
remote amsterdam.perfect-privacy.com 1149
remote amsterdam.perfect-privacy.com 151
remote amsterdam.perfect-privacy.com 150
remote amsterdam.perfect-privacy.asia 151
remote amsterdam.perfect-privacy.asia 150
remote amsterdam.perfect-privacy.org 1149
remote amsterdam.perfect-privacy.info 1150
remote amsterdam.perfect-privacy.asia 149

auth SHA512
auth-user-pass password.txt
client
comp-lzo
dev tun
#float
hand-window 120
inactive 604800
mute-replay-warnings
nobind
ns-cert-type server
persist-key
persist-remote-ip
persist-tun
ping 5
ping-restart 120
redirect-gateway def1
remote-random
reneg-sec 3600
resolv-retry 60
route-delay 2
route-method exe
script-security 2
tls-cipher TLS-DHE-RSA-WITH-AES-256-GCM-SHA384:TLS-DHE-RSA-WITH-AES-256-CBC-SHA256:TLS-DHE-RSA-WITH-CAMELLIA-256-CBC-SHA:TLS-DHE-RSA-WITH-AES-256-CBC-SHA:TLS-RSA-WITH-CAMELLIA-256-CBC-SHA:TLS-RSA-WITH-AES-256-CBC-SHA
tls-timeout 5
verb 4
tun-ipv6

ca ca.crt
cert Amsterdam_cl.crt
key Amsterdam_cl.key
tls-auth Amsterdam_ta.key 1
down /etc/openvpn/update-resolv-conf
up /etc/openvpn/update-resolv-conf
crl-verify ca.crl
```

VPS's ip addr:

```
    lo        Link encap:Local Loopback
              inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
              inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
              UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
              RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
              TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
              collisions:0 txqueuelen:0
              RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

    venet0    Link encap:UNSPEC  HWaddr 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00
              inet addr:127.0.0.2  P-t-P:127.0.0.2  Bcast:0.0.0.0  Mask:255.255.255.255
              UP BROADCAST POINTOPOINT RUNNING NOARP  MTU:1500  Metric:1
              RX packets:27052 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
              TX packets:30619 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
              collisions:0 txqueuelen:0
              RX bytes:3363556 (3.3 MB)  TX bytes:4903075 (4.9 MB)

    venet0:0  Link encap:UNSPEC  HWaddr 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00
              inet addr:84.200.105.209  P-t-P:84.X.x.X  
              Bcast:84.X.x.X  Mask:255.255.255.255
              UP BROADCAST POINTOPOINT RUNNING NOARP  MTU:1500  Metric:1
```

I read that it can be done via Routing but i dont have much experience on Linux and i dont want to crash my Vps, so im asking for your help.

Comment: What you need to do is to configure two separate routing tables to be used depending on source IP of the packets. If the source IP is the one assigned by the VPN the packet needs to be routed through the VPN. Otherwise it need to be routed through the physical interface.

Answer (score 1):

You'll probably find your answer here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/4420/reply-on-same-interface-as-incoming

Your OpenVPN client changes the default route of your server. When you try to SSH in, the TCP handshake doesn't complete, as your server tries to reply through your OpenVPN tunnel. Packet may get lost at some point, or at best would arrive from another IP.

Comment: Correct answer... thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Add a custom route command into your openvpn client config:

```
route add 84.X.x.X 255.255.255.255     <your real default gw>
```

Comment: I have used "route -n" to show my default Gateway but it seems to be 0.0.0.0? Would it be a valid option to use 84.X.x.0 as Gw?

Comment: Don't be noob! Your gateway ip can't end with `.0`.

Comment: See it for yourself: https://gyazo.com/f17259bcdf1df8809b85537ab705a0c9 (Image Link)

Comment: do a `traceroute 8.8.8.8`, please. The gateway will be the first hop.

Comment: Does i need to put the default Gw into < >?